# How to print to JAVAFX gui like printing to console

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, javafx, printing

Trying to print data to a gui made by javafx.

```
...
for(Entry<Date, String> entry : tmap.entrySet()) {
    Date key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
```

I do not want to use `setText()` as it wont act like in console, it will clear to only one text every loop of `TreeMap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is by concatenating the original text with the new content and setting the resulting `String` using `setText`.

In your case you can improve the efficiency of doing this by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textNode.getText());

for(Entry<Date, String> entry : tmap.entrySet()) {
    Date key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    sb.append(key).append(" => ").append(value).append('\n');
    ...
}
textNode.setText(sb.toString());
```

---

In case you're using a `TextInputControl`, [`appendText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-) may be worth a look, but in case you know you're adding multiple `String`s, `StringBuilder` is probably more efficient.

```
for(Entry<Date, String> entry : tmap.entrySet()) {
    Date key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    textNode.appendText(key + " => " + value + '\n');
    ...
}
```